# BigQuery Column with Json Data - Unnest and Extraction

Tags: json, google-bigquery, unnest, json-extract

I'm trying to unnest data from a JSON column into separate rows along with the other data in my table. This is what I have so far...

```
Select 
  *, 
  items 
from 
  project.mytable as libraries, 
  unnest ( libraries.items )

This is the JSON in the "items" column:
     {
      "254718f4-e4f4-40b2-83fd-24ca0c7d96b6": {
        "createdAt": "2020-03-23T18:57:06.820Z",
        "id": "254718f4-e4f4-40b2-83fd-24ca0c7d96b6",
        "parameters": {
          "name": "Access Topics (Webex)",
          "resourceId": "96fae4ec-a448-440b-8faa-badba789417a",
          "type": "video"
        },
        "type": "Resource",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-23T18:57:06.820Z"
      },
      "32a1084c-1cdf-4d15-b438-a3b79310d467": {
        "createdAt": "2020-03-23T04:57:51.656Z",
        "id": "32a1084c-1cdf-4d15-b438-a3b79310d467",
        "parameters": {
          "name": "Launch Update.mp4",
          "resourceId": "993dad8f-6e3c-466b-81d6-25ef5df2fcb1",
          "type": "video"
        },
        "type": "Resource",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-23T04:57:51.655Z"
      }
    }
```

How do you unnest the root items of the json so you can target the fields individually and save them as a field in a BQ table?

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: and what is expected output - provide example please - just attempt to verbally explain usually does not work and lead to confusions

Comment: I agree with @Mykhail. Can you provide the current and the desired output ? So it is easier to understand the issue.